# Access long from another class

Tags: c++, arduino

**Detector.cpp:**

```
#include "Detector.h"

void detectorSniffer(uint8_t *buf, uint16_t len) {
  if(buf[12] == 0xA0 || buf[12] == 0xC0) {
    c++; //Failing to read C long in the detector class
  }
};

void Detector::start() {
  Serial.print("start");
}
```

**Detector.h**

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include "Mac.h"

class Detector {
  public:
    void start();
    unsigned long c = 0; // Variable
};
```

I'm trying to access an unsigned long variable in the `Detector` class from the `detectorSniffer()` function. I've attempted `Detector d` with `d.c` amongst others. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to modify class (member) variables, you have to create an instance of this class first.

Then the best way would be set `detectorSniffer` as method (or friend function) of class `Detector`, after that you can access & modify its member variables from `detectorSniffer`.

```
void Detector::detectorSniffer(uint8_t *buf, uint16_t len)
{
  if(buf[12] == 0xA0 || buf[12] == 0xC0) {
    c++;
  }
};

// Calling
Detector d;
d.start();
d.detectorSniffer(/*parameters*/);
```

or pass reference to an instance of `Detector`

```
void Detector::detectorSniffer(uint8_t *buf, uint16_t len, Detector & d) {
  if(buf[12] == 0xA0 || buf[12] == 0xC0) {
    d.c++; //Failing to read C long in the detector class
  }
};

// Calling
Detector d;
d.start();
detectorSniffer(/*some parameters*/, d);
```

Comment: Or make the detectorSniffer a member method of the detector class (although don't know the author's intentions from a design point of view)

Comment: It happens, no problem :-)